# How to select only records who don't have prohibited key value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select only records who don't have [itrtype] with value of 11,41. Please see my sample fiddle.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&rdbms2=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d71a8fa460813ca02e3028d372fdc0cf

I try (not in) command but seems that result won't fit in my Expected Result.

```
        Query Result
        inumbr  itrloc
        1111    12001
        2222    12002
        2223    12003
        2224    12004

        Expected Result
        inumbr  itrloc
        2223    12003
        2224    12004
```

Comment: Fiddles are great, but the question need to be a standalone [mre] in case the link breaks in future. Please update your question.

Comment: Hi dale, Done already change the question. Thank you

Comment: Um, no? The contents of your fiddle aren't in the question yet?

Comment: hi dale, hope it turn it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do it using window function and I expect to be more effienct and faster:

```
select inumbr,itrloc,itrtype from (
   select *, count(case when itrtype in (11,41) then 1 end) over (partition by inumbr,itrloc) cnt
   from INVAUD
) t
where cnt = 2
```

> ```
> inumbr | itrloc | itrtype
> :----- | -----: | ------:
> 1111   |  12001 |      31
> 1111   |  12001 |      11
> 1111   |  12001 |      41
> 2222   |  12002 |      31
> 2222   |  12002 |      11
> 2222   |  12002 |      41
> 2222   |  12002 |      32
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d35dfda0d678be5973c88a019de0d0c3)*

Comment: Is this query returning expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select inumbr,itrloc FROM (
select inumbr,itrloc, itrtype from invaud
group by  inumbr,itrloc, itrtype having itrtype in ('11', '41'))A GROUP BY inumbr,itrloc
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```